# Visual Studio debugger for SharePoint AutoHosted App

Tags: visual-studio, app, debugging, autohosted

I'm using VS2013 for developing SharePoint Hosted App against a 365 development site.
The VS debugger tool doesn't hit anymore my breakpoints.
It used to the day before.
I have made many tests,

- On the "**Hello World**" sample (with a breakpoint on a simple `alert()`).
- On two different desktops.

Can someone help me to solve that question ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you accidentally changed the code in such a way that its not running to the line you have your break point at. If you edit the post with your code I can look at it for you.

Comment: Thanks Mike. I tried again this morning on my sharepoint basic app (OOB) and it's now debugging. Also on my more complex app. I don't understand why. Seems not to be relied on code. May be relied on the linked between VS and browsers ?

Comment: VS is a great tool, but it does have some strange stuff you have to watch out for. I've had to completely recreate projects because it seems to cache certain things that I can't circumnavigate. Glad it all worked out.

Comment: You are right. In fact, for now, debug issue is coming back. I'm unable to hit breakpoints anymore. Mistery...

Comment: Its unfortunate that you're getting these issues with VS2013, '13 is a HUGE improvement on '12 as far as performance goes. Occasionally when I do run into issues like this and I can determine 100% it isn't my fault then usually (emph. usually) closing and reopening VS resolves it.